# VSCode editor not filling all space available

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, editor

When I open a file in VSCode, its not filling all editor space but instead of that, it stays in the middle and with a small width. How could I fix it to not resize and fill all space available.

The screenshot shows this behavior

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITZAC.png)

Answer (score 2):

Go to `View` > `Appearance` > Untick `Centered Layout`